# Intellij IDEA code style not working on non project files

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea

I'm working on a javascript file that is in the same folder as my project. Intellij does not consider this to be a project file. Does it have to be in it's own module (subfolder) for it to be considered a project file? Because of this, it's not applying my code style to the javascript file (`Preferences→Editor→Code Style→JavaScript`). Which I have set to use tabs instead of spaces. Instead it's using the default 4 spaces for indentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Try right-clicking on root directory of your project and select

> Mark Directory As → Sources Root

---

2. There is a setting, which enables IDEA to [detect indentation style](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2014/10/intellij-idea-14-will-detect-code-styles-on-the-fly/) from existing files, which can then override your global settings. Try disabling it.

[image]

---

3. Check whether you have `.editorconfig` file in your project, as it will override your global IDEA settings.

Comment: The first option I can't do because there isn't a root module. The project has 6 modules in it, and this .js file resides outside of them all. I went ahead and unchecked "Detect and use existing file indents for editing" and that appears to have fixed it! Thank you :)